# Converting meters to miles inaccurate result

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to convert the meters travelled into miles. The problem I'm having is that the results are completely inaccurate and I'm having trouble finding out why.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
CLLocation* newLocation = [locations lastObject];

NSTimeInterval age = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

if (age > 120) return;    //

if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;


if (self.oldLocation == nil || self.oldLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
    self.oldLocation = newLocation;
    return;
}

CLLocationDistance distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation: self.oldLocation];

NSLog(@"%6.6f/%6.6f to %6.6f/%6.6f for %2.0fm, accuracy +/-%2.0fm",
      self.oldLocation.coordinate.latitude,
      self.oldLocation.coordinate.longitude,
      newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
      newLocation.coordinate.longitude,
      distance,
      newLocation.horizontalAccuracy);

NSLog(@"distance is %f", distance);
totalDistanceBetween =+ (distance * 0.000621371192);
NSString *cycleDistanceString = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithFormat:@"%f meters",
                                 totalDistanceBetween];

_CurrentDistance.text = cycleDistanceString;
    self.oldLocation = newLocation;
```

Can anyone give me an idea where i'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it's *best practice* in Objective C to start **ALL variables** off with lower case letters.  In other words, change your outlet named "`_CurrentDistance`" to "`_currentDistance`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code says this:

```
totalDistanceBetween =+ (distance * 0.000621371192);
```

That uses the unary `+` operator, which does nothing.  It seems likely that you meant this:

```
totalDistanceBetween += (distance * 0.000621371192);
```

Also, the units of `distance` is meters (because that is what `distanceFromLocation:` returns), and the units of `totalDistanceBetween` is miles, because 0.000621371192 miles = 1 meter.  But in the next statement, your format string says `%f meters`.  It should say `%f miles`.